# AngularJS rerun a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on ionic+angularjs,

**SITUATION**
I have a list of items, each item redirects to a new page(form). after filling up the form and goes back to the list, the item will be indicated with a checkmark.

from the form, in order to go back to the list i used `$ionicHistory.goBack()`

**QUESTION**
how can i rerun a controller from the list of items, below is the code i used:

HTML:

```
<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-content>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-nav-view>
```

JS:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log('View is shown');
})
```

Comment: You want to rerun the controller on any event ? Try invoking activate method again on event !

Answer (score 0):

Ionic emits events from the view's scope like `$ionicView.enter`, `$ionicView.beforeEnter` which could be helpful for you to re-run your controller logic when the user enters the view.

[Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

Comment: somewhat $ionicView.enter and other events are not firing or triggered.